Python merge/join/concat with boolean condition
I would translate this SQL code (see below) in python code. I think I can use pandas.merge/join but I don't know how define the boolean condition.


create table gg as
select b.*, a.value 
from table b as b left join table a as a
on
b.key eq a.key and
b.date_value >= a.date_start and
b.date_value < a.date_end

I try this code, but where I can define the boolean condition?
df_C=df_B.merge(df_A,'left',left_on='key', right_on='key').copy()


why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

read notice and provide [mre] with your desired ouput in text table.

Yes you can use the merge() function I think.
Try something like this:
# Convert date columns to datetime objects
df_A['date_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df_A['date_start'])
df_A['date_end'] = pd.to_datetime(df_A['date_end'])
df_B['date_value'] = pd.to_datetime(df_B['date_value'])

# Merge with conditions
df_C = pd.merge(df_B, df_A, how='left', on='key')
df_C = df_C[(df_C['date_value'] >= df_C['date_start']) & (df_C['date_value'] < df_C['date_end'])]

print(df_C)


Thanks, this code could be a solution for this example, but with million record dataframe probably is not efficient.
